# Running an executable using localhost php to print

Tags: c#, php, pdf, printing, localhost

I am using a localhost php file :

```
<?php


$source = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\localPrinting\\printTest\\testing123.pdf";
//first try
if(file_exists($source)){
    echo exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\localPrinting\\Release\\AutoPrint.exe");
}else{
    //second try
    sleep(2);
    if(file_exists($source)){
        echo exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\localPrinting\\Release\\AutoPrint.exe");
    }else{
        //third try
        sleep(2);
        if(file_exists($source)){
            echo exec("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\localPrinting\\Release\\AutoPrint.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this php file is to execute an executable file I have that prints a pdf file in a folder.

While testing, executing it from localhost is successful, but the print function does not occur.

```
 //print one by one file
            foreach (string file in fileNames)
            {
                if (file.ToUpper().Contains(".PDF"))
                {
                    string sourceFile = @file;
                    WriteLog("Printing File: " + sourceFile);
                    string destinationFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrintedDocuments"] + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(destinationFile))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(destinationFile);
                    }
                    System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                    PdfFilePrinter printer = new PdfFilePrinter(@destinationFile);
                    int waitedTime = 0;
                    while (!(waitedTime < 5001))
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        waitedTime += 1000;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        printer.Print(3000); //wait 3 seconds
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        WriteLog("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    }
```

Please kindly advise what may have went wrong.